# Catching and handling Uglify errors when using Gulp

Tags: npm, gulp, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify

My Gulp setup is otherwise working fantastically, but it stops if there's an error with my JS files. Until Gulp 4 is finally released, we're all stuck using the less than perfect error system in Gulp... So how can I catch Uglify's errors?

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp
        .src(inputJS)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(uglify(uglifyOptions))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputJS))
});
```

According to the [Uglify documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify), `gulp-uglify` emits an 'error' event if it is unable to minify a specific file. Wherever possible, the `PluginError` object will contain the following properties: `fileName`, `lineNumber`, `message`.

The closest I've gotten it to working is: `.on('error', function(uglify) { console.error(uglify.message) }))`, but it ends up with the above Gulp task ceasing to do any more.

Edit: I realise that there's a number of Gulp extensions that help when dealing with error handling (eg. [Gulp-Util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-util), [Stream-Combiner2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-combiner2), [Gulp-Plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber), etc.) but I don't wish to install a whole new extension just for Uglify (I'm handling my Sass errors just fine without one).

Comment: Why do you have an avatar from one of the worst Star Trek episodes?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems the solution was very simple:

```
    .pipe(uglify(uglifyOptions).on('error', function(uglify) {
        console.error(uglify.message);
        this.emit('end');
    }))
```

Almost exactly what Jeffwa suggested, but no need for `gulp-plumber`. The reason my attempt was stopping is because Gulp `watch` tasks wait until they receive `end` (see: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/259).

Comment: @Chunck It works but the reference for the error is *filename: 'script.js'* in the /dist folder. How do I find out which js file before *concat'ing* is the reason for the error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `gulp-plumber` will help.

```
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp
        .src(inputJS)
        .pipe(plumber(function(error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            gulp.emit('finish');
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(uglify(uglifyOptions))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputJS))
});
```

That should catch any errors emitted and write them to the console.